# finding the probability of A happens before B in die rolling

Tags: probability

I'm thinking about the following old exam question:

A die is rolled infinitely many times, what is the probability that (6,6) (i.e. two consecutive sixes) happens before (1,2)?

Since the expectations of waiting time for (6,6) and (1,2) could be calculated, I was trying to get it from there but I haven't seen the connection between them. Is it possible to get $P(\xi_1<\xi_2)$ with only $E(\xi_1)$ and $E(\xi_2)$, where $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ are the waiting times for $(6,6)$ and $(1,2)$ respectively? I also tried writing down all the possible events and sum them up, but the summation seems to be hard to calculate. Thanks for any help.

Comment: don't they have the same expected waiting times?

Comment: I don't think their expected waiting times are the same... When 6 happens,  if it's not followed by 6 then we need to start over. However, when 1 happens, if it's followed by 1 then we still only need an up-coming 2. The two seems to be different to me. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random variable that represents the time of the first instance of $12$ and $Y$ be the random variable that represents the first time of the instance of $66$. Then $P(X=1)\neq P(Y=1)=0$ and $P(X=2)=P(Y=2)=1/36$ but $P(X=3)\neq P(Y=3)$.

Namely $P(X=3)=\frac{6}{216}$ and $P(Y=3)=\frac{5}{216}$. That's because any sequence $*12$ satisfies $X=3$, but $*66$ only satisfies $Y=3$ if the first roll is not $6$.

So it isn't as simple as the two being equal.

One tricky way to do this is to use a Markov process. Let $s_0$ be the start state. Let $s_1$ be the state of having a string ending in $1$ and not having a prior $66$ or $12$. Let $s_6$ be the state of ending in a $6$ with no prior $12$ or $66$. And let $s_{12}$ and $s_{66}$ be the state of having reached $12$ or $66$ first.

Then you are looking for:

$$(0,0,0,P(X<Y),P(Y>X))=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1,0,0,0,0) \begin{pmatrix}
\frac 46&\frac16&\frac 16&0&0\\
\frac36&\frac16&\frac16 &\frac16&0\\
\frac46&\frac16&0&0&\frac16\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}^n$$

This can be done by expressing $(1,0,0,0,0)$ in terms of the left eigenvectors of the above matrix.

Wolfram Alpha gives me $P(X<Y)\approx 0.5538$ and $P(Y<X)\approx 0.4462$.That is $12$ has a better than 55% chance of coming before $66$.

Comment: It's an easy error to make.

Comment: I do not think that a limiting distribution would provide anything meaningful here.

Comment: Well, you'd think wrong. :) @d125q

Comment: My solution agrees with the simulation I posted quite well. Both approaches I know of provide the same result.

Comment: @d125q I got the same answer you did, but I was wrong that the answer was irrational (which was just a guess.) so how can it not "provide anything meaningful here?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Sorry if I'm hasty to jump to conclusions, but I do get that the chances of $12$ are better than those of $66$.

Comment: Right, I mis-transcribed my values from WA, switching the values. I'll fix it. But the problem is not the limit, and you gave no reason for that complaint. @d125q

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Right, and I apologize for that. I just do not see the connection between the two (technically, the probability of being absorbed in one state vs. another and the limiting distribution). Care to point me to some references? I could do the same with my answer. Sorry again.

Comment: It's not references. $(1,0,0,0,0)A^n$ is $(p_0,p_1,p_6,p_{12},p_{66})$ where $p_i$ is the probability that after toss $n$ you are in each state. Since there is no exit from $p_{12}$ or $p_{66}$, and the probability of never getting to $s_{12}$ or $s_{66}$ is zero, the limit is as stated. @d125q

Comment: It's unclear if you just don't know about Markov processes, or you need additional information about them. (Your answer is essentially a similar Markov process argument. I'm thinking of how to translate it into a similar question about $5\times 5$ matrices.) @d125q

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: It is fine (I know of Markov chains). I was mistaken. I still think that my first solution would be what's expected of an introductory probability course, though; seeing as it amounts to solving a simple linear system.

Comment: Perhaps. I didn't say anything about your solution, only replying to your comment about my solution. @d125q

Comment: Your final sentence has "12" twice. I guess this is a typo?

Comment: Failed correction, thanks. @ByronSchmuland

Comment: Your answer and d125q's are the same. Letting $n\to\infty$ in your expression gives $7/13=.53846$ and $6/13=.46153$ in the limit. I think you should take a larger $n$ value to get the correct digits.

Comment: I rounded to fewer digits, but I got an exact value from some WA calculations. (I did not compute $A^n$ for some value $n$, but rather diagonalized $A$ and ignored the eigenvalues $\neq 1$.  )@ByronSchmuland

Comment: (And I mentioned above that it was the same as his answer.) @ByronSchmuland

Comment: Sorry I only read your answer and not the comments, so I missed that....

Answer (score 1):

Consider this diagram:

[image: Diagram]

Where the text inside the nodes denotes the "state," i.e. the suffix that is of interest. $*$ denotes we have nothing, $1$ denotes we have rolled a $1$, and so on.

Let $\phi(\text{state})$ denote the probability of getting to $66$ before getting to $12$ starting from $\text{state}$. It can be seen (and shown) that $\phi$ satisfies the following:

$$
\begin{align*}
\phi(12) &= 0\\
\phi(66) &= 1\\
\phi(*) &= \frac46\phi(*) + \frac16\phi(1) + \frac16\phi(6)\\
\phi(1) &= \frac36\phi(*) + \frac16\phi(1) + \frac16\phi(6) + \frac16\phi(12)\\
\phi(6) &= \frac46\phi(*) + \frac16\phi(1) + \frac16\phi(66)\text{.}
\end{align*}
$$

We are interested in $\phi(*)$, and solving, we get $\displaystyle \phi(*) = \frac6{13}$. [Quick & dirty simulation in R](https://gist.github.com/d125q/2946a0c5c4af4a933e5f).

---

An alternative solution is given by $B_{1,2}$, where
$$
B = (
I_{3 \times 3} -
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac46&\frac16&\frac16\\
\frac36&\frac16&\frac16\\
\frac46&\frac16&0
\end{pmatrix}
)^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
\frac16&0\\
0 &\frac16
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac7{13}&\frac6{13}\\
\frac8{13}&\frac5{13}\\
\frac6{13} &\frac7{13}
\end{pmatrix}\text{.}
$$

The rows of $B$ correspond to starting with nothing (first row), a $1$ (second row), or a $6$ (third row), while the columns correspond to the probability of finishing in $12$ before $66$ (first column) or in $66$ before $12$ (second column).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming (1,2) means 1 has to come before 2:
   Assuming the question means that **both (6,6) and (1,2)** need to be **consecutive**: The answer is **1/2**. No fancy math here, just logic: Each roll of the dice doesn't depend on the previous roll. The probability of hitting 6 is 1/6. The probability of consecutive (6,6) is 1/36. The probability of 1 is 1/6; the probability of 2 is 1/6. Hence, the probability of consecutive (1,2) is 1/36. Therefore, both (6,6) and (1,2) have equal chance of happening.
   If **only (6,6)** needs to be **consecutive**: The answer is **Sigma of (#rolls-1)/((#rolls-1)!+(#rolls-1)) where #rolls goes from 2 to infinity**. First roll both 6 and 1 have equal probability of 1/6. Second roll has 5/6 probability of not being 6 and needing to restart 6&6 sequence over again; while not hitting 2 on the second roll does not necessitate restarting the 1&2. Therefore probability of getting non-consecutive (1,2) in 2 rolls=1/36, 3 rolls=1/36+1/36+1/36=3/36(first roll probability of 1/6 multiplied by second roll probability of 1/6 or first multiplied by third or second multiplied by third) , 4 rolls=6/36(1*2,1*3,1*4,2*3,2*4,3*4), 5 rolls=10/36, 6rolls=15/36, 7rolls=21/36, 8rolls=28/36, 9rolls=36/36; formula (#rolls-1)!/36. While the probability of consecutive (6,6) is always 1/36 independent of the number of rolls; probability of rolling consecutive (6,6) in 2 rolls = 1/36, 3 rolls = 2/36 (1+2 or 2+3), 4 rolls = 3/36 (1+2,2+3,3+4), 5 rolls = 4/36, 6 rolls = 5/36, 7 rolls = 6/36, 8 rolls = 7/36; formula (#rolls-1)/36. Therefore the probability of getting consecutive (6,6) before non-consecutive (1,2) is: 1/2 in 2 rolls, 2/5 in 3 rolls, 3/9 in 4 rolls, 4/14 in 5, 5/20 in 6, 6/27 in 7, 7/35 in 8, 8/44 in 9 rolls; formula (#rolls-1)/((#rolls-1)!+(#rolls-1)).